# filtering a foreign key on a form and displaying the value with dropdown menu

Tags: django

I'm having issues with it displaying the related table's value. It'd show me `table object`. When I try retrieving it, I get the table value itself, but I cannot get the foreign table value.

form.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Whatever Name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = ForeignTable.objects.filter(user=user, status="Y") | ForeignTable.objects.filter(rel_user=user, status="Y") 
        self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs #the user id can be one column or a rel_user column
```

The output to this is a dropdown menu but it says `ForeignTable object`. This `ForeignTable` is then connected to the `UserTable` with a foreign key. This is where I am stuck. I can't get the list to display. So I tried letting `qs=[(o.id, str(o.user.username)) for o in qs]`. On print I can see my usernames. But it gives an error after my print `list object has no attribute all`. So I looked at the template.

template.html
`{{ form.as_ul}}` this is what i had then I change to see what is in the dropdown I'm looking for `{{form.dropdown }}`. It gave me the same error. So now I have no idea where to look next. Where is this `all` that is it is saying?

Comment: So you want to show `username` in dropdown? What is your python version?

Comment: @AamirAdnan that is correct. Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to define `__unicode__` method on your model, to represent model object in more readable way instead of what it currently shows `ForeignTable object`, do following:

```
class ForeignTable(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        user = self.user or self.rel_user
        return user.username
```

The other approach would be to define custom `ModelChoiceField` where you can change what gets displayed for queryset objects:

```
class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        user = obj.user or obj.rel_user
        return user.username

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dropdown = CustomModelChoiceField(queryset=ForeignTable.objects.none())
    # other fields
```